# Instagram post with HashTag

Tags: android, ios, instagram

I'm mobile developer.
I develop Android App, and iPhone App.

my application have function to share. (like twitter, facebook ...)
I'd like to post picture to Instagram with hashtag from my application.
However, I found information that instagram not allow post with hashtag.

Is it still impossible for me to realize that?
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Instagram API to post images/videos, You can only post using Instagram's app. You can however use webhooks to open an image from your app in Instagram app, and then user will have to continue and do the actual posting in Instagram app. Check this: https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/

Instagram API will only allow you to get posts by user/hashtag/location and you can like/comment/follow. But you cannot add or delete posts, stories or direct messages.

Comment: Thank you for reply. It was very helpful.